# Adding multiple control to single line

Tags: asp.net, html, user-controls, panel, dynamic-data-display

I have make a user control which is design using Divs and on main page am adding that control  problematically in the panel  but when am adding that control is added to next line i want it get added in line by line

thanks in adv.

Comment: Give some code so that we may help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
<div style="float:left;">
```